# No discovered URLs and index covered button is disabled

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I am using Rank Math as an SEO plugin
As per there recommendations as well as google recommendations, I should only add the index XML file

But I got discovered URLs= 0 and index coverage button is disabled

[image]

PS: the site map index has been added 1 month ago!

Comment: Is this a sitemap file that lists URLs directly, or a sitemap index file that lists other sitemaps?   Is this on a domain property or prefix property within Google Search Console?

Comment: This has been asked several times recently.  It appears that Google just takes several months to show the correct counts.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenOstermiller for your help  1. It's sitemap index file that lists other sitemaps 2. prefix property within Google Search Console